# I am having a problem when I try to install firebase-tools using npm command

Tags: firebase, installation

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-27T17_16_33_216Z-debug-0.log

I was trying to download firebase tools and I was expecting it to work properly

Comment: anyone please help I need an answer if you know it please